# Python if ANY of the items in the array exist in the object

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-2.7, object

I want to check if ANY of the items in the array exist in the given object.

Here is my current code that works:

```
if "Mod" in [role.name for role in data.roles]:
```

but if I do this....

```
roles = ["Mod", "Admin"]

if any(roles) in [role.name for role in data.roles]:
```

It doesn't work.

How can I achieve this? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Add quotes where they need to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use set intersection, as in the following *toy example*:

```
roles = ["Mod", "Admin"]

if set(roles).intersection(["Mod"]):
        print("match")
```

**Output**

```
match
```

In your example it will be something like this:

```
if set(roles).intersection([role.name for role in data.roles]):
        do something
```

Or if you prefer:

```
roles = ["Mod", "Admin"]
data_roles = set(role.name for role in data.roles)

if any(role in data_roles for role in roles):
        do something
```

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
roles = ["Mod", "Admin"]
if any(role in [role.name for role in data.roles] for role in roles):
    do something
```

What is it doing?, first of all we have a "role names list" made with the expression `[role.name for role in data.roles]`. Let's call it **`data_role_names`**.
It reduces now to:

```
roles = ["Mod", "Admin"]
if any(role in data_role_names for role in roles):
    do something
```

Then it comes a little of theory about iterables. These are my favourite posts about it: [Introduction to Python Generators](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/) and [Iterables vs. Iterators vs. Generators](https://nvie.com/posts/iterators-vs-generators/).
`any()` expects an iterable. A generator is "[..] **a special kind of iterator**" is an iterable.

The generator is made by the expression in parenthesis. Just try:

```
a = (role in data_role_names for role in roles)

print(type(a))
```

And it prints:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

<class 'generator'>
```

[Any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) will then:

> Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is
>   empty, return False

Which means that for every `role` listed in `roles` (in your example `roles = ["Mod", "Admin"]`) and return `true` if any of them is belongs to `data_role_names`.

Comment: Why is there a `role in` in the beginning?

Comment: [Any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) expects an iterable. I'm building a [generator](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/generator) (which are indeed an iterable) with the expression `(role in *<list>* for role in roles)`. Then, for every element in `roles = ["Mod", "Admin"]`, `any()` will check if belongs to the list and return `true` if any of them are in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `&` instead,

```
find = 'Mod'
roles = ["Mod", "Admin"]

if set(roles) & {find}: # {} converts 'Mod' to set
    print("match")

# output
# match
```